# How to Deserialize JSON Response in Rust without Moving the Response Object?

Tags: rust, json-deserialization, reqwest

## Context

I'm building a small Rust CLI to automate some tasks in Gitlab. I'm using reqwest to send my HTTP requests to the Gitlab API. I'm currently refactoring my code, and now I would like to remove this duplicated code snippet.

```rust
fn main() {
    // ... some code
    let create_branch_response = gitlab::create_branch(&client, &args)
        .expect("An error ocurred while processing your request to create a new branch");
    match create_branch_response.status() {
        StatusCode::OK => (),
        StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST => {
            let json_response = create_branch_response
                .json::<gitlab::GitlabError>()
                .expect("An unkown error happened while creating your new branch!");
            panic!(
                "A validation error ocurred while creating your new branch: {}",
                json_response.message
            );
        }
        _ => panic!("An unexpected error ocurred while creating your new branch"),
    }
    let new_branch = create_branch_response
        .json::<gitlab::Branch>()
        .expect("An error ocurred while reading the response");
    println!("New branch {} created!", new_branch.name);
    println!("URL: {}", new_branch.web_url);
    // Some other code
    let create_pr_response = gitlab::create_pr(&client, &args)
        .expect("An error ocurred while processing your request to create a merge request");
    match create_pr_response.status() {
        StatusCode::OK => (),
        StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST => {
            let json_response = create_pr_response
                .json::<gitlab::GitlabError>()
                .expect("An unkown error happened while creating your new merge request!");
            panic!(
                "A validation error ocurred while creating your new merge request: {}",
                json_response.message
            );
        }
        _ => panic!("An unexpected error ocurred while creating your merge request"),
    }
    let new_pr = create_pr_response
        .json::<gitlab::MergeRequest>()
        .expect("An error ocurred while reading the merge request response");
    println!("New pull request \"{}\" created!", new_pr.title);
    println!("URL: {}", new_pr.web_url);
}
```

My goal is to handle the response's status code on a separate function:

```rust
pub fn handle_response_status(status: StatusCode, resource: String, response: &Response) {
    match status {
        StatusCode::OK => (),
        StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST => {
            let json_response = response.json::<gitlab::GitlabError>().expect(
                format!(
                    "An unkown error happened while creating your new {}!",
                    resource
                )
                .as_str(),
            );
            panic!(
                "A validation error ocurred while creating your new {}: {}",
                resource, json_response.message
            );
        }
        _ => panic!(
            "An unexpected error ocurred while creating your {}",
            resource
        ),
    }
}
```

This code does not work due to the `json` method call which deserializes my response body into a desired struct.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*response` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/util.rs:22:33
   |
22 |             let json_response = response.json::<gitlab::GitlabError>().expect(
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^-----------------------------
   |                                 |        |
   |                                 |        `*response` moved due to this method call
   |                                 move occurs because `*response` has type `reqwest::blocking::Response`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

## What I tried

I already tried the following (sorry, I'm still new to rust).

```rust
let json_response = response.clone().json::<gitlab::GitlabError>().expect(
                format!(
                    "An unkown error happened while creating your new {}!",
                    resource
                )
                .as_str(),
            );
```

But I get the same error.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
   --> src/util.rs:12:33
    |
12  |             let json_response = response.clone().json::<gitlab::GitlabError>().expect(
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------------------------
    |                                 |                |
    |                                 |                value moved due to this method call
    |                                 move occurs because value has type `reqwest::blocking::Response`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |
```

I also tried receiving the response as text and then deserializing with `serde_json`, but calling `create_branch_response.json()` also causes a move.

If you are interested on reading the whole code for better context, here's a branch with these (broken) changes: https://github.com/Je12emy/shears-cli/tree/util_module. Any feedback is appreciated

Comment: Why do you need to do this "without moving"? Your original code consumed `Response`s, why can't `handle_response_status` take an owned `Response` too?

Comment: After handling the error status code on the `handle_response_status` I deserialize the data to print out some information. But you are right, I could do this inside the function, take ownership and not deal with this. I have updated the code snippet to reflect my intent

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a `error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference` is because you are actually [cloning the reference instead of the actual struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#impl-Clone-for-%26T) ([`Response`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/blocking/struct.Response.html)). Rust will implicitly deref the ref for function call for some case (see [Implicit Deref Coercions with Functions and Methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods)), but not for your case since [`reqwest::blocking::Response` does not implement Clone](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/src/reqwest/blocking/response.rs.html#21-26).

[See this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=75e5431ec818f6368eec348e64a233bd)

To solve your borrowing problem, I recommend you to [get the bytes value from request](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/blocking/struct.Response.html#method.bytes), create a `BufReader`, and then use [`serde_json::from_reader`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/fn.from_reader.html) ([reqwest internally use this](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/blocking/struct.Response.html#errors)). Then you can parse the json multiple times.